# Disabling ligatures in section headings

Tags: fontsize, ligatures

I've redefined my `section` headings to be `\Huge` but I don't like the ff and fi ligatures at this size, how can I disable ligatures for sections or above a certain pt size?

I'm using pdflatex with the MinionPro package (Minion Pro for both body text and section headings) and `\documentclass[10pt]{article}` and microtype `(\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}`) but I can move to xelatex or lualatex if necessary.  I'd like to keep microtype expansion though.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\section{I don't like the ff ligature here}

But I do like the ff ligature here!

\end{document}
```

A slight complication, perhaps, is that the document is written in Markdown and the pdf is produced through pandoc.  Pandoc doesn't seem to like suppressing a ligature like `f{}f` but is happy for macros, so my current work-around is to use a macro `f\noligature f` where `\noligature` inserts `{}`.  But this spoils the simplicity of the Markdown syntax.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.  Thanks for providing MWE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you're already using `microtype`, you just need to add the line

```
\DisableLigatures[f]{size=Huge-}
```

This will disable all `f` ligatures for `Huge` or larger sizes, while other ligatures (e.g. `Th`) and all the ligatures in smaller fonts will be typeset as normal:

[image]

(This works with `pdftex` or `luatex` but with not `xetex`.)